# Git commit -am does not work on initial commit. Why?

Tags: git

Why does `git commit -am` not work on my initial commit, but works thereafter?

```
$ touch test.txt
$ ls -a
.  ..  .git  test.txt
$ git commit -am "Initial commit"
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       test.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to first `git add` your file to the repo. `git commit` only commits changes to tracked files, `git commit -a` will commit all changes to tracked files. But untracked files will not be committed at any point.

You'll find that even on commits after the initial, if you create a new file it will not be committed with `git commit -a` until you `git add` it.